# Drupal 7 + JS code through the AJAX

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7

I had created several modules extending the UI elements of the FormAPI. This works fine when I render forms in a normal way (not AJAX). But if the rendered form is delivered though the AJAX request, JS script simply inserts the code via the $.html function. So I can't access elements of the document by their ID from the script evaluated by the $.html.
Is there any solution to pass JavaScript code through the Form/Ajax API?

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery("#new-id") (not $(..)) should take the newest dom elements.
You can use either the 'ajax' property of form api

```
$form['myitem'] = array(
'#type'=>'textfield',
'#ajax' => array(
  'callback' => 'my_callback',
  'wrapper' => 'new-id',
  'method' => 'html',
  'effect' => 'fade',
),
);
$form['myitem2'] = array(
'#type'=>'markup',
'#value'=>"<div id='new-id'> I'm #new-id </div>"
);


function my_callback(&$form, &$form_state){
  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('#new-id', 'html', array('<div id="new-id2">#new.id2 here!</div>'));
  $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('#new-id2', 'addClass', array('error'));
  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

D7 ajax_commands:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7

hope this help

Comment: Yes, that's it. But the problem is in call of jQuery(...).html(...) by the Dialog API, which executes all scripts via the globalEval first, and only then inserts elements to the DOM.